# Switching from active call to a waiting call?

Tags: call-waiting

I'd like to ask you if you know how can I change the line of calling. For example, a friend of mine is calling me and we have a talk. Meanwhile, another one is calling me and at this moment I'd like to start conversation with the second one and to put on hold the first one.
I guess there should be an app for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you are looking to do this programatically this is probably a question for Android-Stack Exchange

Comment: What phone? What version of Android?  Hmm... your question doesn't even mention Android, and you didn't ask this here originally...  Does this even belong here?

Comment: You don't need an app for that. If your network supports it, your phone will just ask you. And you will be able to switch between the two calls.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need and App to do this. This is the basic "Call Waiting" feature.
Go to:

Settings -> Call Settings -> Additional settings -> Enable Call Waiting